# Missing polygons in substance painter

Tags: modeling, texturing

the model looks great in blender (i'm coming back to modelling after quite a while away so it's good enough for now) but as soon as I place it into substance painter large chunks of polygons just aren't loading or appear to be inverted, although I have not inverted a thing on this model.

Does anyone know a way to resolve this? I've tried recalculating the normals but no luck in resolving it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the face orientation overlay? This smells like inverted normals to me but since you say it is not, can you share the file?

Comment: If you could share the blend file or the obj(fbx or whatever) that you imported to painter, it could help greatly.

Comment: Sure i'll send the OBJ over, where would you like it?

Comment: OBJ will do it.